# Reading from AKS Master node

Tags: azure, azure-aks

From whatever i read, i could not find a way to connect to master node in Azure kubernetes Service. I have a requirement to read some parameters like 'enable-admission-plugins' which is possible from master node. Is there any third party api available to get this info.

More specific i need to read the files 'kube-apiserver.yaml', 'kube-controller-manager.yaml'

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible. Masters are managed by Microsoft and you dont have access to them. All the configurations are to be done through the AKS api (mostly when you create it).

> Azure Kubernetes Service (AKS) makes it simple to deploy a managed
>   Kubernetes cluster in Azure. AKS reduces the complexity and
>   operational overhead of managing Kubernetes by offloading much of that
>   responsibility to Azure. As a hosted Kubernetes service, Azure handles
>   critical tasks like health monitoring and maintenance for you. The
>   Kubernetes masters are managed by Azure. You only manage and maintain
>   the agent nodes.

Comment: Can i get some more info on AKS api? Did you mean az cli? Also intend is not to configure but to read configuration.

Comment: well, you can read any kubernetes objects, not those yaml settings files.